# Travis Ci, throws error on ng build

Tags: angular, travis-ci

After research at lot, I was able to build the project. But during the build the external JS are not found. How can I resolve it.

Here is my .travis.yml file

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '7.4'

addons:
apt:
  sources:
    - google-chrome
  packages:
    - google-chrome-stable
    - google-chrome-beta

before_install:
  - export CHROME_BIN=chromium-browser
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0

  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
  - "npm config set spin false"
  - "npm install -g npm@^2"

install:
  - npm install -g angular-cli
  - npm install -g karma
  - npm install
  - ng build

script: 
  - karma start karma.conf.js --single-run
```

Here is the error that is encountered while building

Raw versions of the build: https://api.travis-ci.com/jobs/79351258/log.txt?deansi=true&access_token=rXEZspcQjQiIinqXHkW_qg

Error are, cannot find module `fullcalendar`, `jQuery`, and also cannot find name `$`

Here is the example of how i am using the external js into my-project

```
import { Options } from 'fullcalendar'
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as moment from 'moment';
```